# jQuery Mobile Store data locally and sync when internet is available

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, asynchronous

I am beginner in jQuery Mobile.
I have a simple form which has 10 fields.

My requirement is, when user submit this form check for internet connection if it's available then store the data in DB else store data locally. Whenever internet connection is available sync those data  and upload to server.

how can i achieve this? Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One way to implement this is to use a standard jQuery ajax call to the database.

If it returns an error (which would, among other things, indicate that an internet connection may not be available) copy or move the data (depending on what you need) to an array specifically used as a pending upload queue.

Then have a function running via setInterval to check if there is data in the pending upload queue, if there is try to upload it, if it succeeds remove the uploaded data from the queue. If it fails leave the data for the next try.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this suggestion. Yes that will surly help me. However, how can i store data offline even though user leave my web site or close browser. Please suggest

Comment: You can use the localStorage functionality of HTML5 in most modern browsers which supports basic key=>value pairs (in string format - but with parseInt, parseFloat and JSON.parse or a JSON library you can handle almost any data type), or you could try one of the implementations of Web SQL, but it is much less supported between the major browsers.